# How to store and retrieve data on Angular 6 using Session Storage?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple form, need to store the values on sessionStorage after submit. Also need to show all the items from sessionStorage. To do that

```
import { StorageServiceModule} from 'angular-webstorage-service';
```

Want to create a service to use this StorageServiceModule of angular. How can I implement service using the SESSION_STORAGE. Any kind of documentation link or implementation example will be helpful.

Comment: https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/use-localstorage-sessionstorage-using-webstorage-angular4/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have tried this its works for Local_storage But not working for Session Storage.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the tutorial added by @Chellappan but if you want to store data into session then replace LOCAL_STORAGE to SESSION_STORAGE here like this:

```
constructor(@Inject(SESSION_STORAGE) private storage: WebStorageService) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no much difference between localStorage and sessionStorage.The only difference is that local storage has no expiration set, we need to manually clear the values that are in localStorage. but in sessionStorage values gets cleared, when the page session ends.

for your question on store and retrieve data using session storage. please refer this link,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage